# VMWare: guest machine internet working randomly

Tags: vmware-fusion

I have an issue with the internet in my VMWare guest machine working very randomly (mostly not working) and I am not sure what the issue might be.

Sometimes the internet works (this also includes possibility to ssh to the host), but most of the time it doesn't.

Restarting `networking` doesn't help, nor any `ifdown`/`ifup`'s. The only situation when it might start working is restarting the whole VM. And even then it starts working perhaps one time in 10.

The only potential issue I have noticed so far is that when it doesn't work, VM network adapters' MAC addresses are swapped - while if it works, they are as configured.

Details:

- host: OS X El Capitan 10.11.4 running VMWare Fusion 8.0.1
- guest: Linux debian 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.65-1+deb7u2 x86_64 GNU/Linux

VMWare virtual machine network settings:

- Network Adapter 1 - NAT - static MAC address `00:50:56:38:CC:21`
- Network Adapter 2 - Host only - static MAC address `00:50:56:38:CC:22`

In my virtual machine `.vmx` configuration file I have this (related to the interfaces):

```
ethernet0.present = "TRUE"
ethernet0.connectionType = "nat"
ethernet0.wakeOnPcktRcv = "FALSE"
ethernet0.addressType = "static"
ethernet0.linkStatePropagation.enable = "FALSE"
ethernet0.pciSlotNumber = "33"
ethernet0.address = "00:50:56:38:CC:21"
ethernet0.startConnected = "TRUE"
ethernet0.vnet = "vmnet2"
ethernet0.bsdName = "en0"
ethernet0.displayName = "Wi-Fi"
...
ethernet1.present = "TRUE"
ethernet1.connectionType = "hostonly"
ethernet1.virtualDev = "e1000"
ethernet1.wakeOnPcktRcv = "FALSE"
ethernet1.addressType = "static"
ethernet1.linkStatePropagation.enable = "FALSE"
ethernet1.pciSlotNumber = "37"
ethernet1.address = "00:50:56:38:CC:22"
ethernet1.startConnected = "TRUE"
```

Host `ifconfig`:

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether a0:99:9b:0b:bf:c5 
    inet6 fe80::a299:9bff:fe0b:bfc5%en0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4 
    inet 10.230.82.42 netmask 0xffffc000 broadcast 10.230.127.255
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
en1: flags=963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 6a:00:01:ba:d6:30 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en2: flags=963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 6a:00:01:ba:d6:31 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether a2:99:9b:b0:3e:00 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
    member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 5 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 6 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
p2p0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
    ether 02:99:9b:0b:bf:c5 
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
awdl0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1484
    ether 7a:81:75:a1:0f:87 
    inet6 fe80::7881:75ff:fea1:f87%awdl0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x9 
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
vmnet1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 00:50:56:c0:00:01 
    inet 192.168.247.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.247.255
vmnet8: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 00:50:56:c0:00:08 
    inet 192.168.195.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.195.255
```

Guest `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.195.200
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.195.2

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.247.200
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Guest `ifconfig` (when internet works):

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:38:cc:21  
          inet addr:192.168.195.200  Bcast:192.168.195.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe38:cc21/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:470 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:461 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:74106 (72.3 KiB)  TX bytes:53650 (52.3 KiB)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0x2000 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:38:cc:22  
          inet addr:172.16.121.132  Bcast:172.16.121.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe38:cc22/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1648 (1.6 KiB)  TX bytes:578 (578.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:61 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:61 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:24465 (23.8 KiB)  TX bytes:24465 (23.8 KiB)
```

Guest `ifconfig` (when internet doesn't work):

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:38:cc:22  
          inet addr:192.168.195.200  Bcast:192.168.195.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe38:cc22/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:217 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2472 (2.4 KiB)  TX bytes:9398 (9.1 KiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:38:cc:21  
          inet addr:192.168.247.200  Bcast:192.168.247.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe38:cc21/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:26 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3498 (3.4 KiB)  TX bytes:620 (620.0 B)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0x2000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:219 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:219 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:42755 (41.7 KiB)  TX bytes:42755 (41.7 KiB)
```

Here I can see the only difference - the MAC addresses are the other way round, compared to how they are configured.

When internet works:

- from the guest, pinging all 192.168.195.* works fine (.200, .2 and .1)
- from the host, I can ping myself (.1) and the guest (.200), pinging .2 gives me 'Request timeout' error

When it doesn't work:

- from the guest I can ping myself (192.168.195.200), but pinging any other 192.168.195.* (.2 or .1) gives me 'Destinaton Host Unreachable' error. Same when pinging the internet (for example 8.8.4.4)
- from the host I can ping myself (192.168.195.1), but pinging any other 192.168.195.* (.2 or .200) gives me 'Request timeout' error.

Any idea why this might be happening, and what else I could try?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved now.

I tried the workaround described at https://communities.vmware.com/message/2350978#2350978 - generally creating a new VM using the existing VMDK virtual disk (which re-created all the external VM settings) - it worked flawlessly, even though being a little overkill.

Just in case I have kept the copy of the original problematic VM, and then, after getting [help from the VMWare employee](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2591161#2591088) - which suggested removing the NAT adapter settings (all `ethernet0.` entries) from the VM's `.vmx` configuration file, then removing the network adapter itself, and then re-adding it - everything started working perfectly.

Guess I just had some old settings in the `.vmx` file, from previous versions of VMWare, or old VM configurations...